# Android OpenGL Texture Coloring

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I'm trying to change color of my textures, I have 2 render methods inside my sprite, one without color params and one with, It works fine if there is just 1 object being rendered, but If i render for example 1 colored texture and 1 normal texture, both will be colored
I'm guessing I somehow have to reset the glTextEnvf state but I got no idea how.

Here is my source code

```
public void Render(GL10 gl)
{
   gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);

   gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

   gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, verticesBuffer);
   gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

   gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, vertices.length/2);
   //RESTORE
   gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
public void Render(GL10 gl,float r,float g,float b)
{
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glColor4f(r,g,b,1.0f);
    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);


    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 2);

    //RESTORE
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've called glDrawArrays in the sprite you want to be colored, set the color back to 1:

```
gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Hope this helps